# for each loop in Objective-C for NSMutableArray

Tags: php, ios, foreach, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
NSMutableArray *output = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

or

```
NSArray *output = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

I can set keys and values. Now, I just want to access each key and value, but I don't know the number of keys set.

In PHP it is very easy, something as follows:

```
foreach ($output as $key => $value)
```

How is it possible in Objective-C?

Comment: the answer could be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300256/fast-enumeration-with-an-nsmutablearray-that-holds-an-nsdictionary ? (I mean, it contains the answer, though the question is different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused with NSDictionary with NSArray.

In NSDictionary you can set the object with the keys like

```
NSMutableDictionary *output = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 
[yourDictionary setObject:@"yourvalue" forKey:@"yourKey"];
```

and you can get the object like

```
[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
```

In your Array it just adds the object in the index.

```
NSArray * output = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"option1",@"option2", nil];
```

get the object as

```
[output objectAtIndex:1];  // 1 is the index number
```

Comment: For dictionaries you should use objectForKey, not valueForKey. The latter is meant for Key-Value Coding.

Answer (score 4):

For an NSArray:

```
for (id item in output) {
    // go nuts
}
```

For an NSDictionary:

```
for (id key in output) {
    id value = [output objectForKey:key];
    // go nuts
}
```

I'm using the generic `id` type because I don't know what types of keys and values you are working with. You should use the specific class names if you know them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that manages keys and values

Answer (score 0):

In your example take a second array for the value objects and use a NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: objectsArray
                                          forKeys: output];
```